# My code is suddenly painted yellow (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea

I think I accidentally switched something in the IntelliJ IDEA with some key combination. Now a few places in the code are suddenly painted yellow, as can be seen in the screenshot. Does anyone know how I can remove that.[image]

Comment: It's a bit suspicious that it's only highlighted for cases where the variable name is the same as the right hand side variable ;) that might be some kind of warning that you are doing something unusual (or wrong).

Comment: You can always hover marked code (or the marker in the scrollbar area) to see what IntelliJ wants to tell you